# Show All Data Using python manage.py shell

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have tried to migrate my database but am still having issues. I wanted to try and look at all my sites databases via Command Prompt. I want to try and see which columns do or don't exist in models.

I did `python manage.py shell` but then could not work out the queries that would allow me to see all the information in both my sites databases.

[image]

```
(project2_env) C:\Users\HP\django_project3>python manage.py shell
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from blog.models import Post
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<User: RossSymonds>, <User: RossTheExplorer>, <User: RossSymondsFacebook>, <User: testuser>]>
>>> objects.all()
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use Django migrations for handling alterations to your database so that you do not have to keep track of which columns exist or not in your database

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all of the rows, use a `for` loop.

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    print(user)
```

If you want to see what columns are there, grab an instance and start checking what you have.

```
user = User.objects.first()
print(user.first_name)
print(user.last_name)
# etc...
```